# JavaScript - I don't understand how this collision detection function works

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection

I'm enrolling in this [course](https://www.edx.org/course/javascript-introduction-w3cx-js-0x-0) and they have this function from their code [example](https://codepen.io/w3devcampus/pen/gmEVJG) and I don't understand how this particular one works.

```
function circRectsOverlap(x0, y0, w0, h0, cx, cy, r) {
   var testX=cx;
   var testY=cy;
   if (testX < x0) testX=x0;
   if (testX > (x0+w0)) testX=(x0+w0);
   if (testY < y0) testY=y0;
   if (testY > (y0+h0)) testY=(y0+h0);
   return (((cx-testX)*(cx-testX)+(cy-testY)*(cy-testY))< r*r);
}
```

The first four arguments are the x and y position, width and height of the rectangle, while the last three are the x and y position, and the radius of the circle in the canvas.

If the rectangle and circle touch, the function returns `true`, hence there is a collision.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that testX and testY become the coordinates of the nearest point to the center of the circle enclosed by the rectangle.  The four if tests 'clamp' these values to the edges of the rectangle should the center of the circle be outside of it in either dimension.  It might help to consider the case where the circle is centered inside the rectangle - all the ifs are false and testX and testY are the coordinates of the circle's center.  The test in the return statement uses the Pythagorean Theorem to determine if the test point is within the radius of the circle.

Comment: I somewhat understand, but not fully. Why does it check, if the hypotenuse is lesser than r*r?

Comment: If the nearest point on the rectangle is closer to the center of the circle than its radius, they're overlapping somewhere.   The distance-squared between the nearest point on the rectangle and the center of the circle is (cx-testX)*(cx-testX)+(cy-testY)*(cy-testY), the radius-squared is r*r.  The author probably though that was simpler to write than using JavaScript's Math.sqrt() function on the left side and requiring it to be less than r (which is totally equivalent).